# JPA: JOIN in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I thought I know how to use `JOIN` in `JPQL` but apparently not. Can anyone help me?

```
select b.fname, b.lname from Users b JOIN Groups c where c.groupName = :groupName
```

This give me Exception

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query
Internal Exception: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
```

`Users` have a OneToMany relationship with `Groups`.

`Users.java`

```
@Entity
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Groups> groups = null;
}
```

`Groups.java`

```
@Entity
public class Groups implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USERID")
    private Users user;
}
```

My second question is let say this query return a unique result, then if I do

```
String temp = (String) em.createNamedQuery("***")
    .setParameter("groupName", groupName)
    .getSingleResult();
```

`***` represent the query name above. So does `fname` and `lname` concatenated together inside `temp` or I get a `List<String>` back?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Join on one-to-many relation in JPQL looks as follows:

```
select b.fname, b.lname from Users b JOIN b.groups c where c.groupName = :groupName
```

When several properties are specified in `select` clause, result is returned as `Object[]`:

```
Object[] temp = (Object[]) em.createNamedQuery("...")
    .setParameter("groupName", groupName)
    .getSingleResult(); 
String fname = (String) temp[0];
String lname = (String) temp[1];
```

By the way, why your entities are named in plural form, it's confusing. If you want to have table names in plural, you may use `@Table` to specify the table name for the entity  explicitly, so it doesn't interfere with reserved words:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "Users")     
public class User implements Serializable { ... }
```

Comment: What if instead of selecting fields you selected an entity + a field from another entity. Something like `SELECT b , c.name ...`. Then the first object in the Object[] is gonna be a field of b or the whole entity ?