# How to have multiple conditions in JPQL join

Tags: jpa, jpql

I want to join two tables using `JPQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN 
B ON A.ID = B.A_ID AND B.lng = 'en'
```

The important part is **AND B.lng = 'en'**

Is this possible in `JPQL`?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

I have a similar issue, posted [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633921/atypic-jpa-onetoone-relation

Comment: It works in SQL but can't convert it into JPQL. Adding `AND B.lng = 'en'` condition in **ON** condition list is still not possible using JPQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JPA 2.0 does not support an ON clause, but the JPA 2.1 draft does.

EclipseLink 2.4 supports an ON clause.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON

Comment: HQL supports it using the `with` keyword: `select a from A a left join a.b b with b.language = 'en'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, there is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730625/jpa-join-in-jpql). However, if your entities are mapped, you should be able to access them in a query.

Comment: hi john thanks for the feedback, but where is the example where the `AND` part is in the left join ... NOT in the where

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the and part being in the left join and not in the where?

Comment: Do you mean having two join conditions?

Comment: I did a quick search (assuming that you meant conditional join) http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/JPA/Join/condition.htm

Comment: yeah I meant a conditional outer join