# Atypic JPA OneToOne relation

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem using JPA.

I have to tables:

```
-----------------
| TableA        |
|---------------|
| ID: INT       |
| ...           |
| ESTATUS1: INT |
| ESTATUS2: INT |
-----------------

-----------------
| EstatusTags   |
|---------------|
| COD: VARCHAR  |---> COD and VALUE are a concatenated PK
| VALUE: INT    |
| DESC: VARCHAR |
-----------------
```

EstatusTags is a table to store sets of pairs [VALUE, DESC], given a COD.

Before I use JPA, I used to query this kind of data in something like this:

```
SELECT ID, ESTATUS1, ESTATUS2, E1.DESC DESC1, E2.DESC DESC2
FROM TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN ESTATUSTAGS E1 ON E1.COD = "a_estatus1" 
        AND E1.VALUE = A.ESTATUS1
    INNER JOIN ESTATUSTAGS E2 ON E2.COD = "a_estatus2" 
        AND E2.VALUE = A.ESTATUS2
```

I'm trying to use JPA to model this using two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EstatusTags")
public class EstatusTags implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ValueTagPK id;

    @Column(name="VVA_DESC")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name="VVA_ORDEN")
    private Integer orden;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="ID")
    private String desc;

    @OneToOne(???)
    private EstatusTag estatus1;

    @OneToOne(???)
    private EstatusTag estatus2;
}
```

I have strong doubts in how to model the relations. Can it be done with annotations? There is necesary the JPQL use to fit this structure?

I hope somebody could help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In class `A` `desc` a String  is mapped to column `ID` which according your table is an integer. That does not make sense. In table  `A` ID is the primary key? Also class `A` references `EstatusTag` where as your class is named `EstatusTags`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your entity model does not match the table structure.
In your entity model you have a one to one relation ship between `A` and `EstatusTag` whereas in your table model you have a relationship of one A and multiple Estatustags (for one `value` there may exist multiple Etatustags entries)

You overcome the problem that Table `A` does not have a `cod` column  by adding something like a virtual `cod` column  `E1.COD = "a_estatus1"` to your SQL Query.

What you can do is you map the `value` column of to two properties of `EstatusTag`  one time to the composite pk and the other time to a single property in the following way . The simple `value` is made accessible via property access but marked as not updatable not insertable also the setter does not really work and is made `private`. 
*Remark:* I don't know if that works with all JPA implementations - Tested with hibernate 4.3.8.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EstatusTags" )
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class EstatusTag implements Serializable{


    private @EmbeddedId ValueTagPK id;

    @Column(name="VVA_DESC")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name="VVA_ORDEN")
    private Integer orden;



    @Column(name="value", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public int getValue() {
        return id.value;
    }

    private void setValue(int value) {
        // only because otherwise hibernate complains about a missing setter.
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class A implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="estatus1",referencedColumnName="value")
    public EstatusTag estatus1;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="estatus2",referencedColumnName="value")
    public EstatusTag estatus2;


}
```