# Convert MySql query to JPA named query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, openjpa

I have a `MySql` query like this:

```
select AK.*, max(AA.activityDate) 
from AssessmentKey AK 
join AssessmentActivity AA on AA.ASSESSMENTKEY_ID = AK.id 
group by AK.id having max(AA.activityDate) <=  '2012-10-02 17:30:55'
```

Is there a way to convert into in `JPA` `NamedQuery`. I am using `OpenJPA`.

If I put it directly into:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "AssessmentActivity.findByDate", 
  query = "select AK.*, max(AA.activityDate) from AssessmentKey AK 
           join AssessmentActivity AA on AA.ASSESSMENTKEY_ID = AK.id 
           group by AK.id having max(AA.activityDate) <=  '2012-10-02 17:30:55'")
```

The error is showed here: `select AK.*` that `identifier expected, got "*"` and also it does not like `on`, here it says:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you should replace `AK.*` with `AK` you just need the entity alias here.

Second problem: join syntax is not like that. You should write: `join` and navigate through the object references,eg: AK.assesmentActivity and use the `where` keyword instead of `on`

Here's a tip on join: [JPQL join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730625/jpa-join-in-jpql)

Remember: you are in the ORM, dealing with Entities and their properties, not DB foreign keys and columns.

(ps: Maybe you wanted to write a `NativeQuery`? There you can use native SQL syntax)

EDIT:
(on your comment) So you must start your query from AA:

```
select AK from AssesmentActivity AA join AssesmentKey AK where AA.assesmentKey = AK ...
```

This way you can join them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use NativeQuery and let you know if it worked.

Comment: NativeNamedQuery only works for the current table, it does not loads me other objects related to that table. So I am trying to make a NamedQuery, but there is a problem with join statement. The problem is that I can not do like this: AK.assesmentActivity because my assessment key does not have any mapping to assessment activity only the assessment activity have a many to one mapping on assessment key object. Any ideas how to make it work without changing the database, just how to convert this mysql query to jpql?