# CriterialBuilder, specification, and Predicate. Spring Data solution for Oracle sql exists clause

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I have a sql which is similar to the following. (As I cannot use production database table names and the query is quite messy)

```
select book_name, auther_name, price
from library_books
where book_name=?1, auther_name = ?2, price < ?3
and exists (select * from best_sellers where best_sellers.isbn = library_books.isbn 
and best_sellers.name = library_books.book_name)
```

This is actually a query used for filtering report. As example, if the screen is getting a list of books, user may search all books or filter search based on criteria. In the existing code, the query is concatenated as below

```
if (StrinUtils.isNotEmpty(search_name)){
   sb.append ("book name like '%"+search_name+"'%");
}
```

But now this logic is moved to spring data to use specifications and criteria builder.

```
    public Specification<T> getQuerySpecification(final SearchForm searchForm) {
            return new Specification<T>() {
                @Override
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> recordsRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
criteriaBuilder cb) {
                    Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();

                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(searchForm.getName)){
                        predicate.getExpressions().add (cb.equal(cb.lower(recordsRoot.get("bookName").as(String.class)), searchForm.getName.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))    );
                    }           

                    return predicate;
                }
            };
        }
```

My question is, how do I manage the following part in the original query using spring data. Note that it also involves a different table call best_sellers

> and exists (select * from best_sellers where best_sellers.isbn =
>   library_books.isbn)

Entities would be as following

**LibraryBooks**

- bookName
- authorName
- price
- isbn
- ....

**Best_Sellers**

- name
- isbn
- printsSold

Join is not an option as the actual entities are complex than the one in this example. Hence also do not mind the illogical entity relationship, as this is a sample. Real question is how to use spring data and criteria builder when you need to merge a sub query using "exists". Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post the model.

Comment: @HarshalPatil, added the entities. you see the first native query at the top. my question is how to use criteria builder to exists (subquery). The subquery uses already declared table and a new table

Comment: I need a relationship of entity so i can solve your problem

Comment: there is no relationship. although, (libraryBooks.bookName == bestSellers.name && libraryBooks.isbn == bestSellers.isbn) can be true for some case.

Comment: So here you need to use JPQL.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730625/jpa-join-in-jpql?rq=1
refer this answer.