# INNER JOIN issue with JPQL (even if the SQL request is working)

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, postgresql-10

"bonjour à tous" (hi to everyone)

I'm coming from this thread :
[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

This guy is doing almost what I need in my project.
In fact, I'm trying to do something like Git : retrieve all instances in their last version.
Currently, I have a table "UM", with those attributes:

- int id (primary key, auto generated)
- String name (can be duplicated)
- int version (1, 2, 3, [...])
- String fmr
- [others attributes, not used in this case]

I have also this request in SQL (that working well and retrieves the wanted result):

```
SELECT * FROM agrid.um AS u INNER JOIN
        (SELECT u2.name, max(u2.version) AS MaxVersion, u2.fmr
         FROM agrid.um AS u2 WHERE u2.fmr = 'CZ2ABVIMG0000' GROUP BY u2.name, u2.fmr) umVersion
         ON u.name = umVersion.name AND u.version = umVersion.MaxVersion
         WHERE u.fmr = 'ABCDE';
```

But when I tried to do the same in JPQL, I have some "JOIN" errors:

```
TypedQuery<UmEty> q = getManager().getEntityManager().createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM UmEty u INNER JOIN"
            + " (SELECT u2.name, max(u2.version) AS MaxVersion, u2.fmr "
            + " FROM UmEty u2 WHERE u2.fmr = :fmr GROUP BY u2.name, u2.fmr) umVersion"
            + " ON u.name = umVersion.name AND u.version = umVersion.MaxVersion WHERE u.fmr = :fmr", UmEty.class);
    q.setParameter("fmr", fmr);
    return q.getResultList();
```

With the following exception:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing
[SELECT u FROM UmEty u INNER JOIN (SELECT u2.name, max(u2.version)
AS MaxVersion, u2.fmr 
FROM UmEty u2 WHERE u2.fmr = :fmr GROUP BY u2.name, u2.fmr) umVersion
ON u.name = umVersion.name
AND u.version = umVersion.MaxVersion WHERE u.fmr = :fmr].
[33, 147] The join association path is not a valid expression.
```

I've also tried to simply use "JOIN" instead of "INNER JOIN", and some other tests (remove the "WHERE" clause, ...), but I always have this exception throwed.
I'm not so familiar with JPQL and I've already read the "INNER JOIN" topic on Objectdb (==> https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from ). But even with those information, I'm not able to have a successful request

Can someone tell me why my SQL request translation into a JPQL one is not working ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wasn't a question, just like this one, asked earlier

Comment: The question is: how can I translate this SQL request to JPQL one ? Why do I have "join" issues ?

Comment: Check [JPA: JOIN in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730899/3831557)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I've already try to use only "JOIN" and everything listed in ObjectDB page. But still no working :/

Comment: SQL is much more powerful than JPQL - only a very small subset of the SQL language can be translated directly to an obfuscation layer like JPQL .

Answer (score 0):

For a join to work in JPQL you must have a direct dependency in your object graph to the entity you wish to join.

This example comes from the spec itself :

`SELECT c FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o WHERE c.status = 1`

where `Customer` is an entity with a relationship to an `Order` entity through `customer.orders` list object.

You can read more on joins in chapter 4.4.5 of [Java Persistence Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-spec/index.html)

**EDIT:**

You may wish to rewrite your query to comply with the following format:

`select * from agrid.um u
where u.fmr = 'ABCDE' and not exists 
(select * from agrid.um u2 where u.name = u2.name and u.version < u2.version)
;`

Comment: Ok I see, but it's not my "case".
I just want to work on the same table, and make the JOIN with a pre-selection of the table (the second SELECT clause). Is it possible ?

Comment: afaik you cannot do that query without an explicit relationship declared in your entity model. But you can translate your query to use an **EXISTS** condition.

Comment: Well, sorry if i am wrong but with jpql, you can not create sub select query (except using where and having clause)

Comment: Hi. Someone already said it to me, but I have already did it in another (easier) case. So it's not the problem here :/

Comment: I've edited my answer as to make my comment on using **EXISTS** clearer. If all you want is the maximum version of the entries in that table.

Comment: Hi and thanks again for your help. But it's still not working, because the clause "u.name = u2.name" force the request to retrieve only one UM (always the same, always one name and not the others)