# Project data from different tables to a model

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I defined my model classes like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "emp_address_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

    .......
    .......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String country;
    .....
    .....
}

public class EmployeeDetails {
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    ......
    ......
}
```

How can I write a query using @Query annotation to populate all the EmployeeDetails.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.sample.app.model.EmployeeDetails......")
    List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetails();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The start of the query you wrote looks good to me. And there are a gazillion ways to flatten a 1:M relationship.

Comment: Can you provide me any links in flattening 1:M, Many-to-many relations to a new model via @Query annotation.

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-aggregate-functions.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730625/jpa-join-in-jpql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the constructor in EmployeeDetails

```
public EmployeeDetails(int id,String name,String country){
  this.id=id;
  this.name=name;
  this.country=country;
}
```

Try this query

To get all employee details:

```
SELECT new com.sample.app.model.EmployeeDetails(e.id,e.name,a.country) from Employee e,Address a
```

Comment: Hi Thnx, one minor change is constructor should be public